How do I dynamically update the template based on user logged in status?
I have an issue where if the user is logged in or logged out the sidebar html that is nested should be different. Now i believe the normal way to solve this is to pass down a .LoggedIn value (this means i would have to pass this on every request where the side bar is present, every page).
I am using HTMX, and i believe we are supposed to do this check on the server side and then just send the correct HTML. If i check if the user is logged in on the server i then pass down my base.html with all the nested templates but then need to tell the template to use the correct sidebar, how do i do this?
{{ define "title" }}Page Title{{ end }} 
{{ define "sidebar" }} 
    {{ if .LoggedIn }} 
        {{ template "sidebar_logged_in" . }} 
    {{ else }}
        {{ template "sidebar_logged_out" . }} 
    {{ end }} 
{{ end }} 
{{ define "content" }} 
    <h1>Page Content</h1> 
    <p>This is the main content of the page.</p> 
{{ end }}


What exactly is the issue? Having to pass this info to the template for every request?

No, the issue is i have been told doing any 'if's or sending the 'isLoggedin' to the client is not the HTMX way and instead we should be sending only the HTML to be displayed. The if check should be done on the server and then decide which template to include.
Unless the above way is perfectly fine for HTMX and the .isLogged in is not being sent to the client to render.

The template generates only the HTML to be displayed. The value of .LoggedIn is not included in the generated HTML.

would that mean adding this to every render then as the navbar needs to check this on every page e.g.
return c.Render(200, "profile.html", isLoggedin)
is there a way to auto pass this in via middleware or something else?

[1/2] I'm afraid, there might be some confusion in place. Go's html/template has a quite narrow scope: it defines a markup language which can be parsed and then generate HTML documents at runtime. Each generation has to be performed explicitly (in the Go code). Note that the templating engine is not at all concerned with when this generation is performed and what is done with the result. Say, you can use it to generate static websites. Even if used to power a "live" website, still it's up to you when you pefrom that generation and what you do with its result.

[2/2] I mean, typically, HTML templating is used for what today's webdevs call "server-side rendering": basically, when a client hits some /endpoint of your server, the code serving the request would generate an HTML document which is then returned as the response. If you're talking about an SPA (and, after cursory look at what "htmx" is, I'm sure you are), then the front-end part may indeed perform XHRs to the server and get back HTMLs generated from templates in the server. In this case, it's up to the front-end to communicate in these requests how these templates should be generated.

OK, [3/2] ;-) I mean, if you have front-end code handling login/logout, it's up to it which bits of the UI it updates, and how. It may do a single XHR to replace the whole document or its "main element", and in this case your approach appears to be sound—provided you communicate that "logged in/logged out" state in the request. Or it may perform multiple XHRs, some of which updates the nav bar separately; in this case it will probably have a separate template and a separate endpoint to get its contents. All-in-all, in your question as stated, it's hard to see a clear, narrow problem.

@spotnag Yes, the application must pass the login state to every time a template is rendered.  How to pass the state w/ middleware is outside the scope of the question as stated.

To be honest, I would react to an authentication failure on the server by doing a full page rebuild for a login page and after logging in I would do a full page rebuild to show some kind of starter page. No "if logged in" conditional rendering logic necessary.

It sounds like you want to define a function
type CustomContext struct {
    echo.Context
}

func (c *CustomContext) Render(code int, tmpl string, data map[string]interface{}) error {
    if data == nil {
        data = make(map[string]interface{})
    }
    data["LoggedIn"], _ := c.Request().Context().Value("loggedIn").(bool)
    return c.Context.Render(code, tmpl, data)
}

Then you could have middleware that checks if the user is logged in, and sets the value in the context:
e.Use(func(next echo.HandlerFunc) echo.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c echo.Context) error {
        cc := &CustomContext{c}
        // check if user is logged in
        isLoggedIn := CheckIfUserIsLoggedIn()
        cc.SetRequest(
            cc.Request().WithContext(
                context.WithValue(cc.Request().Context(), "loggedIn", true),
            ),
        )
        return next(cc)
    }
})

And then (I think) you wouldn't have to change your handler code at all (assuming you are passing data as a map[string]interface{} to render already.  Or you may have to rename customContext.Render to something else, go may call the Render on the original context?  But either way that is the general jist of how I would solve it.
